# Swift 4 Properly Parse JSON String to Object

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to parse a JSON string coming from a URLSession request into a Swift object.

I managed to get the data for the first level properties but for nested properties something weird happens. Instead of `:` i get `=` AND strings are missing the double-quotes

How do I access the `date` property inside `published` because I can not do this: `print(todo["published"]["date"])`

Here is the data I get:

```
[
    "pretty_artists": kida, 
    "published": {
        date = "2015-12-05";
        now = 1517005961;
        time = "18.59";
        timestamp = 1449341947;
    }, 
    "views": 36, 
    "yt_id": cyXbV7EUl14, 
    "play_start": 0, 
    "title": ski ide, 
    "duration": 235, 
    "video_name": skiide,
    "artists": kida
    ]
```

Here is my function:

```
func makeGetCall(todoEndpoint: String) {
        // Set up the URL request
        guard let url = URL(string: todoEndpoint) else {
            print("Error: cannot create URL")
            return
        }
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

        // set up the session
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

        // make the request
        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
            (data, response, error) in
            // check for any errors
            guard error == nil else {
                print("error calling GET on /todos/1")
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            // make sure we got data
            guard let responseData = data else {
                print("Error: did not receive data")
                return
            }
            // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
            do {
                guard let todo = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: [])
                    as? [String: Any] else {
                        print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                        return
                }
                // now we have the todo
                // let's just print it to prove we can access it

                print(todo["published"]["date"])


                // the todo object is a dictionary
                // so we just access the title using the "title" key
                // so check for a title and print it if we have one
                guard let todoTitle = todo["title"] as? String else {
                    print("Could not get todo title from JSON")
                    return
                }
                print("The title is: " + todoTitle)
            } catch  {
                print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                return
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: If that's really the data returned it's not valid JSON. Is it from a real web API or is it test data that has typos in it?

Comment: thats the problem. The data is valid JSON.  You can check it here ‘https://kida.al/random’ @mc01

Answer (score 0):

try the SwiftyJSON library, it should help you parse the data more easily.

https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: I would like to do in pure Swift :)